# Separating <Strong> from regular text

Tags: html, css

I want  text to float right and regular text within the `<p>` float right.

When I run this CSS it makes the regular `<p>` text writing right-to-left.

I am using square space so I cannot touch the DIV's or do direction: rtl;

```css
.desc-wrapper strong
{
   color: #000000 !important;
   text-align: left!important;
  font-size: 24px!important;
}

.desc-wrapper p {
   color: #000000 !important;
  text-align: right!important;
  margin-top: -5.7%;
  direction: ltr!important;
}
```

Comment: please provide your html and/or a codepen/jsfiddle

Comment: I can't seem to edit but I want strong text to float left and regular text within p to float right. Both are inside the p tag.

Comment: <span id="mystrongtext"> yourtext </span> try wrapping the text in a span and applying the styles to it

Comment: Can you add your html code, since its very hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If really all you want to do is float normal text right, and `<strong>` text left (and swap their natural order) then you can just do this;

```
p {
  float: right;
}
strong {
  float: left;
}
```

https://codepen.io/sitrobotsit/pen/mmYKwz